# getConnectionManager() when using ApacheHttpClient43Engine RestEasy client v3.6.3.Final

Tags: java, httpclient, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I migrated my WildFly server from 10 to 16. It now uses resteasy-client of version 3.6.3.Final which uses version 4.5.4 of http-client. The problem is I am unable to get connection manager being created internally when I create restEasyClient from builder as shown below:

```
this.resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                .connectionPoolSize(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE)
                .maxPooledPerRoute(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE)
                .build();
```

How can I get connection manager from ApacheHttpClient43Engine engine? My ultimate goal is to get PoolStats from manager which should be **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** in my case [**PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager#getTotalStats**].

The code I am using to get the connection manager is as follows:

```
ApacheHttpClient43Engine engine = (ApacheHttpClient43Engine) resteasyClient.httpEngine();
ClientConnectionManager cm = engine.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager();
```

This method **getConnectionManager()** is deprecated and does not get **HttpClientConnectionManager**.

How can I get PoolStats from my restEasyClient?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` instance created by RESTEasy when building the HTTP Client that way, the reason is that `engine.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager()` returns a different implementation of the deprecated `ClientConnectionManager` interface.

What you could do, instead, is:

1. Creating your own implementation of the `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngineBuilder` interface, extending `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngineBuilder43` and overriding the `createEngine(..)` method: you would simply delegate to super.createEngine(..), but you can store the `HttpClientConnectionManager` instance that's passed as first parameter and which should be what you're looking for.
2. Then you can use the your new custom ClientHttpEngineBuilder to create the ClientHttpEngine to be provided when creating the client:

`ResteasyClientBuilder builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
ClientHttpEngine customClientHttpEngine = newCustomClientHttpEngineBuilder().resteasyClientBuilder(builder).build();
this.resteasyClient = builder
                .httpEngine(customClientHttpEngine)
                .connectionPoolSize(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE)
                .maxPooledPerRoute(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE)
                .build();`

3. Later on, you can access the connection manager from the custom ClientHttpEngineBuilder

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own instance of [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html), configure it, keep a reference of it to work with and explicitly set it via [setConnectionManager()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setConnectionManager(org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager)) of [HttpClientBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) to create a [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) as hinted on the deprecation.

Afterwards just instruct RESTEasy to use that HttpClient instance by creating your own [ApacheHttpClient43Engine](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.3.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ApacheHttpClient43Engine.html) with the appropriate [constructor](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.3.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ApacheHttpClient4Engine.html#ApacheHttpClient4Engine-org.apache.http.client.HttpClient-) and configure it via [httpEngine()](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.3.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html#httpEngine-org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngine-) of [ResteasyClientBuilder](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.3.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html).

```java
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
  new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
  .create()
  .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
  .build();

ApacheHttpClient43Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient43Engine(httpClient);
ResteasyClient resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
  .httpEngine(engine)
  .build();

connectionManager.getTotalStats();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
But when I use custom engine, then the following code of **ResteasyClientBuilder** does not work:
`.connectionPoolSize(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE)
.maxPooledPerRoute(DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE)`
By looking at the source code of ClientHttpEngineBuilder43 class, I think I need to set maxTotal and maxPerRoute of **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager**

Comment: @FaizaAslam You are totally right. I did not test the code. The builder properties are applied to the internally created engine an its dependents only. As you noticed, you have to configure the connection manager directly. I will update my anwser. Nevertheless, I hope you got the idea how to customize the whole RESTEasy client instance.